# Render marker on map with react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to load a marker on the google map but I'm not sure how to do it. In the documentation it shows the next example:

```
const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
     googleMapURL: "api key",
     loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
     containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
     mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
  )(props => (
   <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
      {props.isMarkerShown && (
        <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
      )}
   </GoogleMap>
  ));
  ReactDOM.render(<MyMapComponent isMarkerShown />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But what I am actually trying to do is to create the map component and call it in another component.
The map loads fine when I call it but my question is: how do I pass the marker to the component where I call my map?

This is my map component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = compose(
 withProps({
    googleMapURL:
        "api key",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
 }),
 withScriptjs,
 withGoogleMap
 )(props => (
   <GoogleMap defaultZoom={15} defaultCenter={{ lat: 46.802681, lng: 23.764006 }}>
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
        <Marker position={{ lat: 46.802681, lng: 23.764006 }} />
    )}
   </GoogleMap>
 ));

 export default MyMapComponent;
```

And then I call it in another component like this:

```
import MyMapComponent from './myMap';
const Contact = () => {
   return (
    <div class="contact">
        <MyMapComponent />
    </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Contact` component while returning the `MyMapComponent` pass the **prop** `isMarkerShown` as the way you have defined it in your Map Component as it requires the prop `isMarkerShown` to render the Marker and if you want to pass **dynamic coordinates** to it you could write something like this in your Contact Component:

```
import MyMapComponent from './myMap';
const Contact = () => {
 return (
   <div class="contact">
      <MyMapComponent isMarkerShown lat={49.076} lng={42.8777} />
  </div>
  )
}
```

And in your Map Component:

```
import React from "react";
.
.

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:"API Key",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
   )},
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
 )(props => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={15} 
               defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}>
        {props.isMarkerShown && (
           <Marker position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} />
       )}
   </GoogleMap>
 ));

export default MyMapComponent;
```

Comment: I totally forgot I can pass the lat and lng as props, I'm so damn stupid. Thank you